# How to use diff3 with text arguments instead of file paths?

Tags: bash, files, process-substitution, diff3

I want to use `diff3` with text arguments instead of file paths. For example, `diff3 some_files/mine.txt some_files/older.txt ~/Downloads/yours.txt` works as expected. However, I've been trying to achieve the same result but passing the files' contents instead of their file path and I cannot find a way to do it.

Several attempts were made using `diff3 <(echo <file>) <(echo <file>) <(echo <file>)`, `$(cat <file>)`, special filename `-`, and others... Certainly this is possible, but my BASH/shell skills are lacking!

Comment: `diff3 <(echo foo) <(echo bar) <(echo baz)`.

Comment: @mosvy I had tried that approach, and although it prints the output the program also informs of `input file shrank`, therefore I thought this approach was wrong somehow? Not sure what that message means.

Comment: Indeed by looking at some `diff3` source code it looks like this is a fatal error `else if (feof (infile)) fatal ("input file shrank");`

Comment: Try with here-strings, `diff3` may try to seek, which doesn't work with pipes: `diff3 /dev/fd/3 /dev/fd/4 /dev/fd/5 3<<<foo 4<<<bar 5<<<baz`

Comment: Still the same. Looks like that fatal error only happens when the `-m` option is given to `diff3`

Comment: I can reproduce it with process substitutions (`<(...)`), but not with here-strings (`/dev/fd/N N<<<$var`). Please post some complete example.

Comment: @mosvy I was using version 2.8.1 on Mac OS and I was having that problem. I now experimented on Ubuntu with version 3.6 and it works as you described. I guess Apple won't update it due to the license change in this most recent version. Thank you!